# most commands are refused when prompted for querying whether to use a novice-confusing command

Tags: minibuffer, prompt

When a new user types `M-x narrow-to-region`, Emacs will prompt for a query:

```
Please type y, n, ! or SPC (the space bar): _
```

where the `_` stands for a *cursor*.

Thus, Emacs only accepts these 4 character inputs: `y`, `n`, `!` and `SPC`.

---

It refused most other *command*s and caused some troubles so that I:

- cannot move the *cursor* so that I cannot copy the *prompt-string* to this question.
- cannot `C-x o` to the `*Disabled Command*` buffer (because of the first trouble), which shows some helpful information about the disabled command `narrow-to-region`.  
  In other words, I cannot do anything in that buffer.
- cannot *click* on the hyperlink [`save-restriction`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76235/) in the buffer `*Disabled Command*`.  
  It makes the usage of hyperlink in the sentence:

  > See also [`save-restriction`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76235/).

  meaningless.

---

How to avoid the trouble described by the question title?

---

emacs-version: 28.2; system-configuration: x86_64-w64-mingw32

Comment: Put the version info into the question. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.

Comment: FYI - I just submitted Emacs bug #[62146](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=62146) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dialog is modal: there is indeed no way to go forward other than pressing one of the indicated keys. But:

- You can answer `n` and then visit the `*Messages*` buffer to copy the prompt string.
- The `*Disabled Command*` buffer is for the new user to read, not to do anything with. The contents should be small enough so that a full frame Emacs would show all of it (and you *can* enlarge the frame: that's a WM command outside of Emacs).
- The link is part of the doc string of the command, so after saying `n`, you can always say `C-h f narrow-to-region` and click on the link in the `*Help*` buffer.

Finally, if you think that this behavior should be changed, you can open a bug with `M-x report-emacs-bug` and suggest an enhancement.